# Set typeface to recyclerView items

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need to set typeface to my recyclerView. But the app crashes in this line:

```
var typefaceRegular = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "ProximaNovaRegular.otf");
```

The full code of the class is shown below.

```
    private readonly List<Company> movies;

    private Activity context;

    public MovieAdapter(List<Company> movies)
    {
        this.movies = movies;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        var movieViewHolder = (MovieViewHolder)holder;
        movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.Text = movies[position].CompanyName;
        var position_new = position + 1;
        movieViewHolder.MovieCount.Text = position_new.ToString();
        //FONTS
        var typefaceRegular = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "ProximaNovaRegular.otf");
        movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.SetTypeface(typefaceRegular, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
        //FONTS ENDED
        movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.Click += delegate
        {
            movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.Context.StartActivity(typeof(ClientLogin));
        };

    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        var layout = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MovieRow, parent, false);

        return new MovieViewHolder(layout, OnItemClick);

    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return movies.Count; }
    }

    void OnItemClick(int position)
    {   
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom TextView like this

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "greyScaleBasicRegular.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

In xml File this

```
<com.xxx.xxx.views.CustomTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_back_edit_profile"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/toolbar_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following this instruction:[Calligraphy plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/calligraphyxamarin)

Also I downloaded Calligraphy plugin by NuGet